# Store an array into another array for use outside of scope

Tags: java, arrays, string

Question: I need to store the values of lengthCount[j] into an array outside of the scope. \

What I have tried: To add a return statement into the for-loop and making the code into a method.

What are the variables: 
lengthCount = [I@78db81f3
j = assigned in for-loop

The code below returns the correct result to the console, but I can't store the correct data into an array for use on the outside of the scope.

What I am trying to do: To take a string, count the letters of each word and then find out how many of each length word there are. E.g. 3 words with 3 letters, 1 word with 1 letter.

My current output:

```
String length: 0 count: 0
String length: 1 count: 2
String length: 2 count: 2
String length: 3 count: 4
String length: 4 count: 4
String length: 5 count: 1
String length: 6 count: 1
```

So you can see the code is outputting the correct data, how can I store this into an int array?

```
for(int j=0; j<lengthCount.length;j++){
    System.out.println("String length: "+j+" count: "+lengthCount[j]);
}
```

If you require any more information, please just leave a comment and I will add it rapido!

Thanks in advance!

Full Code

```
public class lengthCountReturn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInput = "I do not like green eggs and ham I do not like them Sam-I-Am";
        userInput = userInput.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "");
        String str[] = userInput.split(" "); // split the strings: "I", "am", "going", etc

        int maxLength = 0;

        for(String s: str)   // finding the word with maximum size and take its length
          if(maxLength < s.length())
                maxLength = s.length();

        int lengthCount[] = new int[maxLength+1]; 


        for(String s1: str)
        {
           lengthCount[s1.length()]++; // count each length's occurance
        }
            System.out.println(lengthCount);
         for(int j=0; j<lengthCount.length;j++)
         {
             System.out.println("String length: "+j+" count: "+lengthCount[j]);
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. `lengthCount` is already an array. Which scope? the one of the loop? then again `lengthCount` is already outside the scope.

Comment: UmNyobe I'll add the whole code at the bottom for reference :)

Comment: actually add the desired output

Comment: Can you show the scope you're trying to use this outside of?  How are you declaring lengthCount?

Comment: I want the number that is printed out after "count: " to be stored into an int array outside of the scope.

Comment: Use an array lengths[] where lengths [j]  = lengthCount[j]

Comment: In a comment on an answer, you say you found "it difficult to word the question".  That's fine.  But your full code compiles fine.  What is it that you want to do?  Could you present it as code?  You say that you want the numbers in `lengthCount` "to be stored into an int array outside of the score".  How does `lengthCount` not do this?  What code would you like to be able to do, but can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using apache commons you have a one line solution but works only with primitive types and their equivalent objects ( int and Integer, byte and Byte, etc):

Lets say that you have;

```
import org.apache.commons.lang;

String[] source = {"hello", "world", "foo", "bar"};
```

Just do:

```
String[] clone = ArrayUtils.subarray(source, 0, source.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define a variable in the scope you need it, and use it in the inner scope.

```
int[] newArray = new int[lengthCount.length]
for(int j=0; j<lengthCount.length;j++)
{
    newArray[j] = lengthCount[j];

}
```

However all this code is doing is copying the values from `lengthCount[]` into `newArray[]`, which could be achieved with one call to `System.arraycopy()`. (All your original code did was print the contents of `lengthCount[]`).

So your question "how can I store this in an array" makes little sense: it's already in an array.

For "real" code you should investigate the Java Collections API, which gives you more expressive ways to work with data like this. If you are just learning Java, you'll get to Collections soon.

Comment: I was finding it difficult to word the question. Sorry if this caused you any problems

Answer (score 0):

In which structure do you wish to store the result ?

I would suggest a Map, for each length `lengthCount[j]`, test if the key exist, add one to the value if yes, otherwise add the key with value 1.

Comment: Later on I will be presenting the data in a bar chart. So I would store it like so. arrayName[] = {1,0,3,2,1,6,3} 1 being 1 1 letter work and 3 being 3 7 letter words.